# Python : Best way to do an infinite loop with an async function

Tags: python, loops, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I have a Discord Python script that retrieves data every second via an API. This data is then displayed as a bot status message. But with time, `while True` + `async` seems to crash after few hours and doesn't send anything without displaying any error. Here is the code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  while True :
    data=api()
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=data))
```

I was told that the best way to make a script run continuously was to enter the script in crontab but since discord only works with asyncio the script does not finish and therefore cannot be restarted by cron. Moreover the minimum frequency is 1 minute.

Do you have any solution ?

Thanks

Comment: Add the 1 second wait in the code and use something like watchdog or supervisor to make sure the process restarts if it fails, perhaps

Comment: I don't understand why this question was closed as opinion-based, it has a clear problem (while loop crashes) and is asking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `ext.tasks` which is provided by the library. Here is an example

```py
from discord.ext import commands, tasks


@tasks.loop(seconds=60) # will repeat every 60 seconds
async def change_presence():
    data = api()
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=data))


change_presence.start()
bot.run(...)
```

The above code **Will break** if you are using master branch of dpy
if you are on master branch, start the task in the following manner

```py
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands, tasks


@tasks.loop(seconds=60) # will repeat every 60 seconds
async def change_presence():
    data = api()
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=data))

async def main():
    async with bot:
        change_presence.start()
        await bot.start(...)

asyncio.run(main())
```